# Reporting option for Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, crystal-reports

I am looking for a way to implement reporting in Silverlight 4. Based on my research, I haven't found much details. I am not sure if i can use Crystal reports.

I am also considering a good third party solution that does offer reporting capabilities.

Looking forward to some feedback.

Thanks
jay

Answer (score 0):

Yep... there is no much to say about reporting except that we have to implement this kind of stuff manually. Check [this](http://www.silverlightshow.net/news/Silverlight-Reporting-Open-Source-Printing-Reports-Example-Updated-for-Silverlight-5-.aspx) alpha project.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am looking for more complex reporting functionalities. There are some other solutions that I found DevExpress/telerik controls that offer some reporting.